# Squares in a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, legendre-symbol

I need to find all prime $p$ s.t $n+3$ is the inverse of $n-3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. So obviously this means $(n+3)(n-3)=1\mod p$, meaning $n^2=10\mod p$. So the question is - for which $p$ does the equation $x^2-10=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{F}_p$, but I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I tried using $(\frac{10}{p})=10^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\mod p$ but this got me nowhere. Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: If $n$ fixed? Is it "there exists an $n$ such that..."? It surely is not "for all $n$", since you can take $n=p-3$ (if $p\gt 3$) and get that $n+3=p$ which is not invertible at all...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For some $n$

Comment: You should use quadratic reciprocity, of course....

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thing is, I'm not used to using quadratic reciprocity, atleast not with such ease. Is it possible that you show me how do I use it in this example?

Comment: $\left(\dfrac{10}p\right)=\left(\dfrac{2}p\right)\left(\dfrac{5}p\right)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I know that $2$ has a square root iff $p=8k+-1$, but I can't tell exactly for which $p$ $5$ has a square root.

Comment: See the entry for $a=10$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Law_of_quadratic_reciprocity

Comment: By quadratic reciprocity, $\left(\dfrac{5}p\right)=\left(\dfrac{p}5\right)$, so $5$ has a square root iff $p\equiv\pm1\bmod5$ for $p>5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is to determine all primes for which there exists an $n$ for which $n+3$ is the inverse of $n-3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$. As you note, this requires finding an $n$ such that $n^2\equiv 10\pmod{p}$, i.e., find the primes for which $10$ is a quadratic residue. Which of course just begs for Quadratic Reciprocity.

If $p=2$, then any even $n$ will work. If $p=5$, then any multiple of $5$ will do. So we may assume that $p\neq 2,5$.

We know that, from the quadratic character of $2$, that
$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 &\text{if }p\equiv \pm1 \pmod{8}\\
-1 &\text{if }p\equiv \pm3 \pmod{8}.
\end{array}\right.$$
And from Quadratic Reciprocity, we have
$$\left(\frac{5}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right)(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\,\frac{5-1}{2}} = \left(\frac{p}{5}\right) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1 & \text{if }p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5},\\
-1 &\text{if }p\equiv \pm 3\pmod{5}.
\end{array}\right.$$

Since $\left(\frac{10}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)\left(\frac{5}{p}\right)$, we see that $10$ is a square modulo $p$ if and only if both $2$ and $5$ are squares modulo $p$, or neither is. So there are $8$ remainders modulo $40$ where it is a square (four for the possibilities that it be $\pm 1$ modulo $8$ and $\pm 1$ modulo $5$; and four for when it is $\pm 3$ modulo $8$ and $\pm 3$ modulo $5$), and $8$ remainders modulo $40$ where it is not a square (the remaining combinations/remainders modulo $40$ that are relatively prime to $40$).  So use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to figure out those values.

Comment: First of all thank you for the detailed answer. Secondly, if I understand correctly, I need the CRT in order to say that if $p=1 \mod 5$ and $p=3\mod 8$ then $p=3\mod 40$?

Comment: @GalBenAyun: Use `\bmod`, not `\mod`, for the binary  modular operator: compare what you have with $p=1\bmod 5$.  Second: I think you made a typo there. The CRT would tell you that $p=1\bmod 5$ and $p=3\bmod 5$ if and only if $p=11\bmod 40$. The point of using the CRT is to replace conditions that involve a conjunction of a modular condition modulo $8$ and one modulo $5$ with a single modular condition modulo $40$.

Comment: Why does $p=1\bmod 5$ and $p=3\bmod 8$ mean $11\bmod 40$? I can't see the reasoning behind it

Comment: @GalBenAyun: By the CRT, there is one and only one remainder modulo $40$ that corresponds to $1\bmod 5$ and $3\bmod 8$. Note that $11=1\bmod 5$ and $11=3\bmod 8$, so that is **the** value modulo $40$ corresponding to that pair. Of course, you can go through the actual constructive proof of the CRT and verify that the solution to $x\equiv1\pmod{5}$ and $x\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ is $x\equiv 11\pmod{40}$, but here the values are small and you can just eyeball them.

Comment: @GalBenAyun: It should be clear that the answer cannot be $p=3\bmod 40$ as you claim, because $p=3$ is congruent to $3$ modulo $40$, but is **not** congruent to $1$ modulo $5$...